# excel 2010 time difference and message

Tags: excel-2010

How can I compare the time difference between two dates in excel? I want one of the following messages to be displayed (1-2 months, 2-4 months, 4-6 month, 6-9 months or 9 months+). If the time difference is either 2,4,6,9 months + extra days then it should be rounded up. If the number of months and days is within the correct time bracket then it should just display that message.

Here is an example list of dates and what the time difference output should say:

```
Start Date     End Date    Desired Message
21/06/16       29/08/16    2-4 months
12/20/16       29/08/16    6-9 months
06/06/16       29/08/16    2-4 months
28/02/15       29/08/16    9 months +
```

so taking the first on the list: 21/06/16 - 21/08/16 = 2 months. 2 months + 8 days = 29/08/16 therefore 2 - 4 months.

Comment: Are those actual dates or text? Some of the Start Dates are dd/mm/yy and some mm/dd/yy ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your date format.

Let's say A1 is your start date and B1 is your end date.

First get month count between these two dates and then keep these in C1

```
((YEAR(A1)-YEAR(B1))*12+MONTH(A1)-MONTH(B1))*-1
```

Then

```
=IF(C1=1,"1 - 2 Months",IF(AND(C1>=2,C1<4),"2 - 4 Months",IF(AND(C1<6,C1>=4),"4 - 6 Months",IF(AND(C1>=6,C1<9),"6 - 9 Months",IF(AND(C1>9),"9 Months +","Not valid date")))))
```

[image: Example]